# Jzmq producer doesn't block when consumer is full

Tags: java, zeromq

I have set up a ZeroMQ pipeline through VPN. However, the producer doesn't consider the consumption capacity of consumer. The producer keeps sending messages to the consumer due to which the RAM consumption has increased extremely.

I want to find the reason behind this problem. Maybe its due to UDP VPN channel.

Comment: Please give a proper reason for the downvote. If something is missing I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *<sub>( find **the reason** behind this problem )</sub> Maybe its due to UDP VPN channel.*

---

### Disclaimer,
<sub>given the ultimate Information Asymmetry is still pending here :</sub>

Well,
given there are so far Zero-pieces-of-information (the less the Community promoted ***MCVE*** ~ **M**inimum-**C**omplete-**V**erifiable-**E**ample-of-code-based problem formulation), either about the UDP channel, or about the composition, configuration and interconnection(s) of ***"producer"*** and ***"consumer"*** entities, except of just mentioning the ZeroMQ by itself, this answer can be and will be based but on generally available knowledge.

---

### Answer :

ZeroMQ framework is based on a few, rather cardinal, principles :

**Rule 1 )** it is Broker-**less** - i.e. the resulting ecosystem resembles a network of **independently** working agents.

**Rule 2 )** user can implement whatever add-on capability, so as to extend the **Rule 1**.

This said, if you configure your application-domain behaviour of your ZeroMQ-interconnected agents in proper manner, the local agent may receive some indication from remote agent(s) about its(theirs) problems with RAM ( for details about possible restrictive configurations of sets-of-Tx/Rx-queue(s) see the well published API documentation )

---

### Finally :

It is almost sure the UDP, the less the VPN has **hardly anything to do with the *"problem"***,

> <sub>( the producer **doesn't consider** the consumption capacity of consumer. )</sub>

as this is the by-design property of the ZeroMQ concept, unless one implements any application-domain specific distributed-FSA layer, atop the ZeroMQ trivial scalable formal communication pattern archetypes, that would provision such app-level *add-on-service* signalling/messaging among the otherwise autonomous agents ( ZeroMQ `Context()`-instance equipped agent-alike entities ).

> If interested, feel free to read more about ZeroMQ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20is%3Aanswer) & get inspired by it's beauties and powers